# Passing a Powershell object as a string parameter

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am currently trying to write the following Powershell script which, in SharePoint terms, retrieves the Central Administration url (retrieved in `$adminUrl`) and then opens an Internet Explorer window with that url.

I'm also appending another string to `$adminUrl` before passing it to the `Navigate` method:

```
$adminUrl = Get-spwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"} | select Url

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate($adminUrl + "/someurl") # <= Trying to pass the url here
$ie.Visible = $true
```

But I'm getting this exception when trying to do so:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Navigate" and the argument count: "1".
At \\a\setup.ps1:9 char:1
+ $ie.Navigate($adminUrl)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Am I facing a casting issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$adminUrl is an object with a url property so you need to use a sub-expression to pass:

```
$ie.Navigate($adminUrl.Url + "/someurl")
```

or with a sub-expression:

```
$ie.Navigate("$($adminUrl.Url)/someurl")
```

You could pass the value of $adminUrl only if you expand the value of the Url property first:

```
 ...| select -ExpandProperty Url
 $ie.Navigate("$adminUrl/someurl")
```

Comment: +1 Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I thought that with the `select` I was simply directly returning the url, but it actually returns an object containing that member.  Thanks for your answer.